# Building apr-utils from Source on CentOS 7 -- dependancy issue

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

Im attempting to build apr-utils-1.6.1 from source on CentOS 7 (with the goal to get httpd-2.4.29) but I'm stuck with a dependancy issue:

```
# rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2
error: Failed build dependencies:
    db4-devel is needed by apr-util-1.6.1-1.x86_64
```

db4-devel isn't available in yum and libdb-devel provides version 5, which doesn't meet the dependency requirement.

I've tried downloading and installing db4-devel, but that has it's own dependencies that I can't meet:

```
# rpm -iv db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    db4 = 4.7.25-22.el6 is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    db4-cxx = 4.7.25-22.el6 is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    libdb_cxx-4.7.so()(64bit) is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
```

Trying to install db4 fails too because the the Berkely DB version 5 is already installed and in use on CentOS 7:

```
# rpm -iv db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    db4 < 5 is obsoleted by (installed) libdb-5.3.21-20.el7.x86_64
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed at this point. Do I just have to cut my losses and deploy a CentOS 6 box? It seems that CentOS 6 still has db4. I was thinking of modifying the spec file to remove the db4 requirement, but I'm not sure of the implications of that, or how to even do that properly.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you can use `compat-db47, compat-db-headers` http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/ ... And edit your `apr-utils.spec` to use the compat packages.

Comment: I'm willing to give it a go, but I've never edited a .spec file. Do you have a good resource that might provide some tips on trying this?

Answer (score 0):

> rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2

No spec file, but apr-util-1.6.1/build/rpm/apr-util.spec.in

Better use a source with a regular `apr-util.spec` file : `apr-util-1.6.1-1.fc27.src.rpm` http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/27/SRPMS/Packages/a/apr-util-1.6.1-1.fc27.src.rpm

Please do not build rpm packages as root, setup an unprivileged rpmbuild environment in /home/name/ :  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

Unpack the source with `$ rpm -Uvh apr-util-1.6.1-1.fc27.src.rpm` ... and `$ cd rpms/SPECS/` ... edit 'apr-util.spec' to the new dependencies, and give it a try : `$ rpmbuild -bb apr-util.spec`

Answer (score 0):

In Redhat release 7.5 is required to install the db4-devel package but it was replaced with libdb-devel. The below steps are necessary to create the packages for apr-util from the tar-ball file

- yum install libdb-devel
- rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2
- cd ~/rpmbuild
- rm -rf BUILD BUILDROOT RPMS SRPMS
- cp ../ apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2  SOURCES/
- cd SPECS
- vim apr-util.spec and replace db4-devel by libdb-devel
- rpmbuild -bb apr-util.spec
- cd ../RPMS/x86_64
- All the packages for apr-util will be there.